# Limiting Distribution of a Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding how to find a limiting distribution.  If I have a Markov Chain whose transition probability matrix is:
$$
\mathbf{P} = \matrix{~ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
              0 & q & p & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
              1 & q & 0 & p & 0 & 0 \\
              2 & q & 0 & 0 & p & 0\\
              3 & q & 0 & 0 & 0 & p \\
              4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
              }
$$

where p>0, q>0 and p+q=1

How would I go about finding the limiting distribution?  Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no stable limiting distribution. The transition matrix is not diagonalizable.

---

The Markov chain has this state diagram:

[image]

Now suppose that at an arbitrarily large number of steps later, the chain is in state $0$ with probability $a$, state $1$ with probability $b$, state $2$ with probability $c$, state $3$ with probability $d$, and state $4$ with probability $e$, and suppose, for contradiction, that this is a constant limiting distribution.

Then

$$a = bp + e$$

$$b = aq$$

$$c = bq$$

$$d = cq$$

$$e = dq$$

Substitution gives $e = aq^4$, so

$$a = aqp + aq^4 \Rightarrow 1 = qp + q^4$$

We also know $p+q=1$, so

$$1 = q(1-q)+q^4$$

$$q^4 -q^2 + q - 1$$

$$q^2(q+1)(q-1)+1(q-1)=0$$

Since $q \neq 1$,

$$q^3 +q^2 +1 = 0$$

This has no positive solutions for $q$ (by inspection). Therefore, there is no stable limiting distribution.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Diagonalize the matrix $\mathbf{P}$.

Comment: It's not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

P is a right transition matrix and represents the following Markov Chain:

[image: State Transition Diagram]

This finite Markov Chain is irreducible (one communicating class) and aperiodic (there is a self-transition). Thus, it has a limiting distribution which is the solution of

$$
π = π P
$$

This limiting distribution corresponds to the normalized left eigenvector of P with eigenvalue 1 and positive entries which is

$$
π = \frac{p^5-1}{p^5-p^4}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{p^4} & \frac{1}{p^3} & \frac{1}{p^2} & \frac{1}{p^1} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Relevant Mathematica notebook [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t3heqzAZFOHv9OJo6_jfDiguBGUGDbPX/view?usp=sharing).